# Create azure .NET version 3 function after version 3 discontinuation

Tags: .net, azure-devops, azure-functions, runtime, deprecated

In the recent past .NET support has been terminated for azure function 3 version. Still I need to create azure version 3 function apps till the those are migrated to version 4. I get run time cannot be found exception when I try to create function apps in version 3 through azure DevOps pipeline agent. Any solution is appreciated.

```
 az functionapp create --name ${{FunctionName }} --os-type Windows --resource-group ${{resourceGroup }} --storage-account ${{ appTierStorageAccountName }} --runtime dotnet --functions-version 3 --plan ${{ appServicePlan }} --app-insights ${{ appInsightsName }} --app-insights-key $(AppInsightsInstrumentationKey)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you share your pipeline code? Hard to debug, based on the exception. It does not say that explicit that it has anything to do with version 3.

Comment: @Peter added the query

Comment: can you create without using azure devops pipeline?

Comment: impossible in the portal too, but using the local machine azure cli it was possible after changing the global .NET version to 3. But it didnt work in pipeline @GingYuan-MSFT

Comment: What about the rest of the pipeline? What runtime are you using/is installed in DevOps? The full yml file?

Comment: Hi @Peter could sorted it by creating the function in the version 4 by pipeline first and then downgrading the function version to 3 using azure cli step, will update the complete solution in to the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted this by creating the function app in version 4 as it allows currently for the dotnet run time and later downgrade the function version

1. Create the function app , set settings and restart the app service

   ```
      az functionapp create --name ${{ clientFunctionName }} --os-type Windows --resource-group ${{ resourceGroup }} --storage-account ${{ storageAccountName }} --runtime dotnet --functions-version 4 --plan ${{ appServicePlan }} --app-insights ${{ appInsightsName }} --app-insights-key $(appInsightsInstrumentationKey)
      az functionapp config appsettings set --name ${{ clientFunctionName }} --resource-group ${{ resourceGroup }} --settings FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION=3
      az functionapp restart --name ${{ clientFunctionName }} --resource-group ${{ resourceGroup }}
   ```
2. Deploy the function app
3. Set .NET version

   ```
      az functionapp config set --name ${{ clientFunctionName}} --resource-group ${{ resourceGroup }} --net-framework-version v6.0
   ```